# Pymongo: Aggregate all documents that not have one field and have another - group by

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm trying to get a set of documents from my collection with the following conditions:

- field: img_status doesn't exist
- field: images should exist

And then, group those documents (unique/distinct) by one field.
When I execute the query in MongoDB, it seems as if it returns the correct values:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
{ $match: { images: { $exists: true, $ne: null } } },
{ $match: { img_status: { $exists: false } } },
{ $group : { _id:"$vendor_link", "uuid" : {$first: "$uuid"}, "images": { $first: "$images"} } }
])
```

But in PyMongo, I always get the opposite like: `img_status exist = true`:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": 
        {   
            "images" : 
            { "$ne" : "null", "$exists": "true", } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": 
        {   
            "img_status": 
            {"$exists": "false"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$group":
        {
            "_id"       : "$vendor_link",
            "images"    : {"$first": "$images"},
            "uuid"      : {"$first": "$uuid"},
            "source"    : {"$first": "$source"}
        }},
]
pprint(list(self.collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the issue. You are passing string values instead of `None` and boolean values `True` and `False`

```py
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {   
            "images" : {
                "$ne" : None,
                "$exists": True,
            } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "img_status": {
                "$exists": False,
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group":{
            "_id"       : "$vendor_link",
            "images"    : {"$first": "$images"},
            "uuid"      : {"$first": "$uuid"},
            "source"    : {"$first": "$source"}
        }
    },
]
pprint(list(self.collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```